# "Would of course be" vs. "of course would be"

Tags: verbs, adverbs, word-order

I am not sure about the position of 'of course' inside a sentence.

Please consider these two versions and comment on that:

> 1. A comprehensive documentation would *of course* be highly valuable...
> 2. A comprehensive documentation *of course* would be highly valuable...

Comment: I also prefer v.(1).

Answer (score 0):

The first option implies a gentler criticism than the second. The second implies that "any fool would know this".

Comment: That's litcrit, Sir.